# Node.js Express server with Wix client side?

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, squarespace, velo

I am fairly new to web programming and I am trying to create a web application using Node.js and Express as the server side module. So far, I am getting the functionality up and running with localhost and a local MySQL database, but I haven't moved on from bare HTML and Javascript on the client side. I have seen that the likes of Squarespace and Wix can provide beautiful template solutions to websites and I was hoping to use that to design the final product (I am by no means a web designer).

Is it possible to integrate my current Node.js Express server with a front end created using Wix or Squarespace?

Comment: amazing question !